# Comparing values of two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries as follows:

```
a = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
b = {1:5, 3:6, 7:1}
```

For every key in `a`, I want to check if the key exists in `b`, if so, I want to print the value of both keys, if it does not, I print `0` as the value of the key in `b`:

```
for key in a.keys():
    if key in b.keys():
        print key, a[key], b[key]
    else:
        print key, a[key], '0'
```

The output would be:

```
1 2 5
3 4 6
5 6 0
```

But, I also want to print the value of key in `b` if it does not exist in `a`, that is the opposite of the last statement, if key is in `b` but not in `a`, print the value of the key in `b` and `0` as the value of the key in `a`. The output would be:

```
1 2 5
3 4 6
5 6 0
7 0 1
```

It should be simple but I can't figure out how I can do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate through all keys from either dictionary, and print their values from the two dictionaries, using `'0'` if the key is missing from that dictionary. Something like this:

```
for key in set(a)|set(b):
    print key, a.get(key, '0'), b.get(key, '0')
```

`set(a)|set(b)` is the union of the sets of keys from each dictionary (i.e. it is a collection of distinct keys from either dictionary).

`dictionary.get(key, '0')` returns `'0'` if the key is missing from the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! How is it possible that set(a) works without having to write set(a.keys())?

Comment: @Homap Because iterating through a dictionary iterates through the keys. A dictionary behaves like a container for its keys. This also applies to `for k in mydict` and `if k in mydict`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in set(a.keys()) | set(b.keys()):
    print key, a.get(key, 0), b.get(key,0)
```

`|` means union in a set context. You can also convert the resulting set into a list and sort it before iterating.

Comment: Just so you know, in Python 3, you don't need to convert the results of `dict.keys` to a set.

Answer (score 0):

Use dict `b`'s `get` method, supplying a default value for use when the key isn't found.

```
for key in a:
    print key, a[key], b.get(key, '0')
```

Comment: How does this show the keys that are in `b` but not in `a`?

Comment: I was assuming the reader would be capable of extending a recipe for finding the keys in `a` but not in `b` to a recipe for finding the keys in `b` but not in `a`. My mistake ...